# Trying to create makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

The files I have are `main.cpp`,`zipType.cpp`,and `zipType.h` and I need to create hmwk.exe.

This is what I have:

```
    CC=g++
    CFLAGS=-g -Wall
    SOURCE=main
    SOURCE2=zipType     

    hmwk.exe : $(SOURCE).o $(SOURCE2).o
             $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) -o hmwk.exe $(SOURCE).o $(SOURCE2).o 

    $(SOURCE).o : $(SOURCE).cpp $(SOURCE2).h
             $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE).cpp 

    $(SOURCE2).o : $(SOURCE2).h $(SOURCE2).cpp

    clean:
             rm *.o
```

I don't need it to be extravagant, I just need it to work. This is the output I'm getting:

```
    $ make
    make: Circular zipType <- zipType dependency dropped.
    make: *** No rule to make target `.h', needed by `zipType'.  Stop.
```

Thanks for any help! I really don't like makefiles lol.

Comment: I bet dollars to doughnuts you have whitespace after "zipType" on the line that says `SOURCE2=zipType`.  Welcome to `make`!

Comment: no space, anything else look wrong? I just don't get why my teacher won't let me just type g++ *.cpp and be done with it! lol

Comment: Check again. The code you pasted in here certainly has trailing spaces; selecting the line pastes it as `"SOURCE2=zipType_____"` (underscores mine for visualisation - 5 spaces in total).

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I didn't look for trailing spaces. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
SOURCE=main
SOURCE2=zipType     

hmwk.exe : $(SOURCE).o $(SOURCE2).o
         $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) -o hmwk.exe $(SOURCE).o $(SOURCE2).o 

$(SOURCE).o : $(SOURCE).cpp $(SOURCE2).h
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE).cpp 

$(SOURCE2).o : $(SOURCE2).h $(SOURCE2).cpp
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE2).cpp 

clean:
         rm *.o
```

However, I think the simple way is just :

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
SOURCE=main
SOURCE2=zipType     

hmwk.exe : $(SOURCE).cpp $(SOURCE2).cpp
         $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: top one doesn't change anything, the simple way you posted gives:

Comment: `g++     zipType.cpp   -o zipType
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.25-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `WinMain'
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.25-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39:(.text.startup+0x7e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target `zipType' failed
make: *** [zipType] Error 1`

Comment: The error if I use the first answer is `$ make
make: Circular zipType <- zipType dependency dropped.
make: *** No rule to make target `.h', needed by `zipType'.  Stop.`

Comment: IF you use the following command directly:
g++ -o hmwk.exe -g -Wall main.cpp zipType.cpp

Comment: You're code was just fine, The above comment pointed out I had trailing spaces,that was my problem. Thank you!